# Apache2 won't show index.php

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

so i've started by setting up apache2 up on my ubuntu server. However it seemed to work fine however it did only show index.php as plain text, so i tried to use following command `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5` and now it just show nothing when i access my server. it should be said that i've changed the listener port in `ports.conf` to 5055. Why am i not getting anything after installing libapache2?

so in order what i've done is

```
 sudo apt-get install apache2
 sudo nano /etc/apache2/ports.conf
 sudo service restart apache2
 sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
```

Comment: Anything interesting in `/var/log/apache2/error.log` ?

Comment: Been a while since I used Ubuntu, doesn't it have a program to enable Apache modules? See also the second answer in the dupe.

Comment: Also, why you installing PHP 5? Current version is 7.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these. You might be missing something.

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server libapache2-mod-auth-mysql php5-mysql
sudo apt-get install php5 php5-mysql php-pear php5-gd php5-mcrypt php5-curl
```

This was taken from [TrueSpot Media](https://www.truespotmedia.com/install-lamp-linux-apache-mysql-php-ubuntu/) - https://www.truespotmedia.com/install-lamp-linux-apache-mysql-php-ubuntu/

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following:

```
sudo apt-get install php5
sudo service restart apache2
```

If I am right however in assuming you are running Ubuntu 16.04, please instead run the following command:

```
sudo apt install php libapache2-mod-php
```

Comment: `E: Package 'php5' has no installation candidate` and getting error `HTTP ERROR 500`

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu 16?

Comment: Wouldn't that be a dependency of `libapache2-mod-php5`?

Comment: It would.. But I assumed OP would have included the command if he had installed PHP.. I also assume from the error above that OP is running Ubuntu 16.04 - in which case he should really be installing php7. The entire process should be done with a single command: "sudo apt install php libapache2-mod-php"